# CC1101 sniffing 868Mhz Protocol from thermostat

Tags: arduino-mega, network

Hello i buyed a cc1101 because I want to sniff thermostat protocol which works with 868 Mhz.

I found this repo https://github.com/veonik/arduino-cc1101.
I tried to download the repo and include the zip file as libary.
First error was cc1101.h not found. So I moved the files from .src folder one level up.
Then I get error SPI.h no file directroy. So I imported this libary.
Now I have no errors and uploaded it to arduino mega.
Then I have no serial output. I have a cc1101 with 868 mhz. And I want to log the informations from a MAX! thermostat. Somebody can help me?
Here is photo from my wiring.

[image]

[image]

Comment: SPI on Mega is not on pins 11 to 13, but on 50 to 52. 50 is SO, 51 is SI. 53 is the usual CS as it is the SS if Mega is slave. why do you wire over breadboard? use black wire for ground, red for VCC. didn't you get a pin header with the module?

Comment: Ok thank you. No pin header. Should I change the programm?

Comment: no changes in sketch. change the wiring and wire the additional pin CC1101_GDO0 to 19

Comment: `So I moved the files from .src folder one level up.` -- Sounds like you're on Linux, and you installed Arduino from the Debian APT repository. Uninstall it and download a version from this decade from Arduino.cc

Comment: I changed the wiring. Now I get only CC1101_PARTNUM 0
CC1101_VERSION 20
CC1101_MARCSTATE 13
CC1101 radio initialized.
showed in serial monitor