# Sniffing thermostat protocol CC1101 868MHZ

Tags: network

I am using this libary from github:https://github.com/veonik/arduino-cc1101

With this example code. I will try to read the data which is send from a 868Mhz thermostat. I am using a arduino Mega and wired it like in the following picture.

[image]

First I get this error:

[image]

When i upload the code. I get this Serial Output. But no packages send and no packacges recived. Can somebody help me?

```
   CC1101_PARTNUM 0
CC1101_VERSION 20
CC1101_MARCSTATE 9
CC1101 radio initialized.
```

example code:

```
 #include <Arduino.h>
    #include <cc1101.h>
    #include <ccpacket.h>

    // Attach CC1101 pins to their corresponding SPI pins
    // Uno pins:
    // CSN (SS) => 10
    // MOSI => 11
    // MISO => 12
    // SCK => 13
    // GD0 => A valid interrupt pin for your platform (defined below this)

    #if defined(__AVR_ATmega2560__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega1280__)
    #define CC1101Interrupt 4 // Pin 19
    #define CC1101_GDO0 19
    #elif defined(__MK64FX512__)
    // Teensy 3.5
    #define CC1101Interrupt 9 // Pin 9
    #define CC1101_GDO0 9
    #else
    #define CC1101Interrupt 0 // Pin 2
    #define CC1101_GDO0 2
    #endif

    CC1101 radio;

    byte syncWord[2] = {199, 10};
    bool packetWaiting;

    unsigned long lastSend = 0;
    unsigned int sendDelay = 5000;

    void messageReceived() {
        packetWaiting = true;
    }

    void setup() {
        radio.init();
        radio.setSyncWord(syncWord);
        radio.setCarrierFreq(CFREQ_868);
        radio.disableAddressCheck();
        radio.setTxPowerAmp(PA_LongDistance);

        Serial.begin(9600);
        Serial.print(F("CC1101_PARTNUM "));
        Serial.println(radio.readReg(CC1101_PARTNUM, CC1101_STATUS_REGISTER));
        Serial.print(F("CC1101_VERSION "));
        Serial.println(radio.readReg(CC1101_VERSION, CC1101_STATUS_REGISTER));
        Serial.print(F("CC1101_MARCSTATE "));
        Serial.println(radio.readReg(CC1101_MARCSTATE, CC1101_STATUS_REGISTER) & 0x1f);

        Serial.println(F("CC1101 radio initialized."));
        attachInterrupt(CC1101Interrupt, messageReceived, FALLING);
    }

    // Get signal strength indicator in dBm.
    // See: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/swra114d/swra114d.pdf
    int rssi(char raw) {
        uint8_t rssi_dec;
        // TODO: This rssi_offset is dependent on baud and MHz; this is for 38.4kbps and 433 MHz.
        uint8_t rssi_offset = 74;
        rssi_dec = (uint8_t) raw;
        if (rssi_dec >= 128)
            return ((int)( rssi_dec - 256) / 2) - rssi_offset;
        else
            return (rssi_dec / 2) - rssi_offset;
    }

    // Get link quality indicator.
    int lqi(char raw) {
        return 0x3F - raw;
    }

    void loop() {
        if (packetWaiting) {
            detachInterrupt(CC1101Interrupt);
            packetWaiting = false;
            CCPACKET packet;
            if (radio.receiveData(&packet) > 0) {
                Serial.println(F("Received packet..."));
                if (!packet.crc_ok) {
                    Serial.println(F("crc not ok"));
                }
                Serial.print(F("lqi: "));
                Serial.println(lqi(packet.lqi));
                Serial.print(F("rssi: "));
                Serial.print(rssi(packet.rssi));
                Serial.println(F("dBm"));

                if (packet.crc_ok && packet.length > 0) {
                    Serial.print(F("packet: len "));
                    Serial.println(packet.length);
                    Serial.println(F("data: "));
                    Serial.println((const char *) packet.data);
                }
            }

            attachInterrupt(CC1101Interrupt, messageReceived, FALLING);
        }
        unsigned long now = millis();
        if (now > lastSend + sendDelay) {
            detachInterrupt(CC1101Interrupt);

            lastSend = now;
            const char *message = "hello world";
            CCPACKET packet;
            // We also need to include the 0 byte at the end of the string
            packet.length = strlen(message)  + 1;
            strncpy((char *) packet.data, message, packet.length);

            radio.sendData(packet);
            Serial.println(F("Sent packet..."));

            attachInterrupt(CC1101Interrupt, messageReceived, FALLING);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That is not serial output. That is compiler output. To see serial output open the serial monitor.

Comment: Also note that 868MHz is not the frequency. It is the *band*.  That band is typically subdivided into a number of channels with a specific bandwidth (no standard, but implementation specific). The actual frequency could be anywhere between 865MHz and 870MHz.  You should use an SDR dongle (I use RTL2832U) to both locate and capture the data. Also note that there are multiple different modulation techniques that you will need to account for.

Comment: I updated the question. @Majenko thank you. When I capture the data with the RTL2842U, how can I then capture the data with the cc1101. Because I dont get any data with the cc1101. I understood that the RTL2843U is to understand the protocol. But how can I read the data with the cc1101? Or do you mean it is impossible to read the data from thermostat with cc1101?

Comment: I'm so confused: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/62605/cc1101-sniffing-868mhz-protocol-from-thermostat

Comment: This was another problem I already solved...

Comment: Why is this not part of your question from yesterday on the exact same topic?

Comment: because it is another problem. I can delete this topic and change the question from yesterday. If you want it.

Comment: Before you can start messing around with a CC1101 you first have to know exactly what it is you are trying to capture. You can't configure the CC1101 until you know some basic facts about the transmission. Such things as: what is the carrier frequency? What is the modulation system used? Is there a sync word at the start of a packet, and what is it? How long is the packet? Is there a CRC that needs calculating? Without that information the CC1101 can't receive any data.

Comment: Just because the CC1101 runs in the same frequency band it doesn't necessarilly follow that it will be able to receive the data. After all Bluetooth and WiFi both run in the 2.4GHz range. So does the nRF24L01. And none of them can communicate with each other.

Comment: @Majenko, it appears that the CC1101 has "asynchronous mode" which allows the raw data to be read